# How to access an array stored in a different js file

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I'm trying to create my own lorem ipsum app and I want to keep my code clean by storing my word bank in other files. How can I access an array stored in a different JS file? For example, instead of hardcoding `harry = ["", "", ""]`, I want to store that data in a different file and just call that file into the array.

```
// generator.js
function GenerateNewText(){
this.sentences = [
    harry = [
        "I am the chosen one!",
        "Boy wizard",
        "Quidditch seeker"
    ron = [
       "I am a Weasley",
       "Gryffindor",
       "Quidditch keeper"
    ]
  ]
}

GenerateNewText.prototype.getRandomSentence = function() {
   let randomSentence = this.sentences[0][Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sentences.length)]
   return randomSentence;
}
```

Currently, I have a harryText.js which contains

```
// harryText.js
harryText = [
  "I am the chosen one",
  "I am a Gryffindor",
  "I am a boy"
]

module.exports = harryText;
```

but doing this in my generator.js shows `harryText is not defined`

```
function GenerateNewText(){
this.sentences = [
    harryText,  <---- error here
    ron = [
       "I am a Weasley",
       "Gryffindor",
       "Quidditch keeper"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I tried requiring it like so 
`const harryText = require("./harryText.js")` 
and the problem persists. I'm guessing a scope issue?

I tried installing `ejs` and changing `harryText.ejs` and including it like `<%= include harryText %>` in the generator array and that's invalid code.

Is calling an array from another file and storing it within another array even possible? Does anyone know a solution to this?

And yes, I know a Harry Potter Ipsum already exists. This is just dummy text.

Comment: It looks like you never declared the `harryText` variable in `harryText.js`. You just started using it without saying `const` or `let` first.

Comment: Even after including either const or let in the harryText.js it still says ReferenceError: harryText is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript files are isolated from each other. To share common code you always need `require` and `module.exports`

So you are doing the right thing with `module.exports = harryText`

You then need to `require` that file in `generator.js`

```
const harryText = require("./harryText");
function GenerateNewText(){
this.sentences = [
    harryText,
    ron = [
       "I am a Weasley",
       "Gryffindor",
       "Quidditch keeper"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I did require it in the generator.js but it still shows that harryText is not defined.

Comment: Nevermind, I get what you mean now. I had a `const loremIpsum = new GenerateNewText()` that I didn't include in my OP and so when I saw your answer I mistakenly included `const harryText = require("./harryText")` as so like your example but under my `const loremIpsum`, instead of above it. So unwittingly I created a scoping issue. Anyway, your answer helps. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES6 you can do following.

```
//file1.js
  export const harryText = [
     "I am the chosen one",
     "I am a Gryffindor",
     "I am a boy"
  ]

//file2.js
  import {harryText} from './file1.js';
  // use variable here
```

Comment: If you run this code directly in browser it won't work. You need babel to transpile it. If you environment set up doesn't support es6, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2/20/19 16:15
I was getting the harryText is not defined error because I kept foolishly defining the variable in the wrong place! First I defined it outside of the `function GenerateNewText`, then I tried defining it inside the `this.sentence`. Instead, I should have been defining it inside the `function GenerateNewText` and outside `this.sentence`, like so

```
function GenerateNewText(){
  const harryText = require("./harryText");
  const ronText = require("./ronText");
  this.sentences = [
    harryText,
    ronText
  ]
}
```